# spreading the table captions for subfloats

Tags: tables, captions, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

Hello I am trying to spread the caption of a subfloat in a table to be in one line but could not figure out a way to achieve that.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\mytab}{% Just for this example
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    \toprule
    One & Two & Three \\
    \midrule
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}%
  \tiny
  \centering
  \subfloat[here is an example caption to illustrate my question]{\mytab}%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[]{\mytab}
  \caption{Here are some tables in a \texttt{table} environment.}%
  \label{tbl:table}%
\end{table}

\end{document}​
```

Is there a way to have the caption for Table 1a in one line while having the table centered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

If switching to `subcaption` is an option, here is how you could achieve the expected single-line subcaption:

[image]

(Vertical lines indicate margins.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\mytab}{% Just for this example
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    \toprule
    One & Two & Three \\
    \midrule
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}

\captionsetup[sub]{font=footnotesize}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}%
  \tiny
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\linewidth}\centering
  \mytab
  \caption{here is an example caption to illustrate my question}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\linewidth}\centering
  \mytab
  \caption{caption}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Here are some tables in a \texttt{table} environment.}%
  \label{tbl:table}%
\end{table}

\end{document}​
```